# Change toolbar colour on scroll without collapsing

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to make my toolbar change colour on scroll without actually collapsing it (so I don't want the height of it to change). I want it to be one colour initially and then it will change to another when you scroll. It should then change back to the original colour when I scroll back to the top.

I've been able to change the colour on scroll but only in conjunction with the height changing. I've tried setting minHeight on the Toolbar, CollapsingToolbarLayout and AppBarLayout, but no luck unfortunately.

I know that I can probably do this manually (animate the colour on scroll change) but I want to rule out doing it with the design library first.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/app_secondary_darker">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:text="Abc"
                android:background="@color/grey_light"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:text="Def"
                android:background="@color/red_dark"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hope helpful.

```
app_bar.addOnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
    val collapsedPercent = -verticalOffset / appBarLayout.totalScrollRange.toFloat()

    //仅在这 0.3的区间里交互 //这个值 在  （0,1]之间，可以自定义
    //这里表示仅在收缩到仅剩百分比hotPercent的时候，才进行收缩
    val hotPercent = 0.3F

    val collapsedHotPercent = MathUtils.clamp(collapsedPercent / hotPercent + 1 - 1 / hotPercent, 0F, 1F)

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate collapsedPercent:" + collapsedPercent)

    tabs.apply {
        val normalColorStart = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.k6_main_tabs_normal_start)
        val normalColorEnd = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.k6_main_tabs_normal_end)
        val selectedColorStart = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.k6_main_tabs_selected_start)
        val selectedColorEnd = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.k6_main_tabs_selected_end)

        val normalColor = ColorUtil.getColorOfDegradate(normalColorStart, normalColorEnd, collapsedHotPercent)
        val selectedColor = ColorUtil.getColorOfDegradate(selectedColorStart, selectedColorEnd, collapsedHotPercent)

        setTabTextColors(normalColor, selectedColor)
        setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(selectedColor)
    }
}
```